# How to ignore newline in the end of openssl md5 command-line?

Tags: command-line, openssl, newline, md5

I know we can get the right output in below ways:

> echo -n 123456 | openssl md5
>   **e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e**

or

> printf 123456 | openssl md5
>   **e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e**

or

> printf 123456 > file.txt
>   openssl md5 file.txt
>   **e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e**

However, I want to know could we work it out in below command-line with extra options

> openssl md5 <<< '123456'
>   **f447b20a7fcbf53a5d5be013ea0b15af**( this is incorrect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` (and `ksh93`, and `zsh`) will *always* append a newline to the content of the here-string.  There is no way around this apart from filtering it out explicitly.

```
$ tr -d '\n' <<<'123456' | openssl md5
(stdin)= e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e
```

Comment: I think you are right after lots of try and search, thanks a lot for your answer.